# Order Dataframe in R based on Values in one column (strings)

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataset in R and would like to sort the whole Dataframe  by the values of one column. 
The Values are strings and there are only three possible values in this column (Teenager, Twenties, 30+). 
I want the Dataframe to be ordered in  this exact order.

The name of my dataframe is age, the name of the column is Category.

I already tried

```
> age[order(Category),]
```

which indeed orders the values but in this order: 30+, Teenager, Twenties.
Is it somehow possible to tell R the exact order I want to have?

Btw I am a beginner, obviously :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factor`´s and the `dplyr` package for arranging your data. Factors can handle levels which can be ordered as you want. For example:

```
# load dplyr
library(dplyr)

# generate example df
age <- data.frame(Category=c("Teenager", "Twenties", "30+", "Teenager"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

# mutate the Category variable as factor with orderd levels
age <- age %>% 
  mutate(Category=factor(Category, 
                         levels=c("Teenager", "Twenties", "30+"), 
                         ordered=T)) %>% 
  arrange(Category)
```

By the way, [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html) you can finde a introduction to dpylr. This is very usefull for data handling.

P.S.: Happy learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the column to the correct order.

```
Category <- factor(as.character(Category), levels = c("Teenagers", "Twenties", "30+"))
```

So now you can do

```
age[order(Category),]
```